# Deploying angular js app with spring boot backend in aws

Tags: angularjs, amazon-web-services, deployment, spring-boot

I'm new to using aws , so really sorry if I'm asking something stupid.

I have built my angularJS app which using REST APIs that i made using spring boot. Since i call a session cookie from the same domain. 
As most of my API authorizes users using http cookie

```
     (www.example.com) and not (xyz.example.com)
```

I would now have to keep all my API's and client code coming from the same domain.

How can i manage that with aws ?

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: enable cors to allow api access from subdomain

Comment: I tried and that was my plan but the problem is when i send http cookie to client from a sub domain. I have the cookie in my response header but it the browser doesnt seem to save it in cookies. When i tried sending from same domain. It saves. Didnt find anything on the net, so thought to use same domain

Comment: avoid saving auth info in cookies keep it in session, that ways you can pass it to both domain & subdomain, thought manually, but thats better from security point

Comment: http only cookies aren't a better solution. I read on docs of stormpath and they seem to say storing in session has fallback as it can be accessed by JS where as http only cookie cant be read client side. What do you think ?

Comment: they can be read by client side right, but only your website js code can read them, not other website.